# Ruby cgi redirect to url

Tags: ruby, redirect, cgi

How can I redirect to another url e.q. http://google.com using Ruby (not ROR) in a CGI script?
I tried something like this:

```
cgi.out("status" => "303", "Connection" => "close", "Content-Length" => 1, "Location" => 'http://www.google.com') {' '}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you paste the full script you used, or was that what you pasted? It seems incomplete.

Comment: That's all that had something to do with redirecting. This may be a nonsense, but I have no idea how to do this and that's all I found in google.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using a `.htaccess` level directive or some kind of web server configuration directive if you're just redirecting. Employing CGI for non-programmatic tasks is massive overkill.

You can usually get away with something like this if you're using Apache:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) http://www.google.com/
```

Other server types have equivalent directives.

If you're doing Ruby CGI I think you're doing it wrong. It's not that hard to wrap something simple in Rack or use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) to give you a clean environment to work in. It's faster than CGI, it's more flexible, and best of all, it works well.